# Custom draw ListView but need to show the 3 dots at the end if longer then column width

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, gdi

In NM_CUSTOMDRAW, I draw something and return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT. But the 3 dots at the end do not show if the text is longer then column width.

How to show the 3 dots but allow custom draw?

Comment: Are you replacing the drawing of the text? Then surely you know what area you're drawing to. `DrawText()` can add the ellipses if needed IIRC. Otherwise you just check the text length and shorten/add the ellipses yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DrawText` API to draw your text with the `DT_END_ELLIPSIS` flag. More info here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249678